# Content overflows out of content area

Tags: html, css

I have a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AhSzg/).
Why are list items overflow out of the white content area and how can i fix it?

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background:#7D93BD;
    font-size: 22px;
}
#content {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
    #profileInfo {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}
#profileInfo li {
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
#profile_info_title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `#profileInfo` to be pushed down by 100px, then use `margin-top` instead of `top`:

```
#profileInfo {
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove top:100px from the #profileInfo ul - it's pushing that content down by 100px.

Comment: If i put top:100px it means it has to be there. As soon as my rep point is 125 i will press down vote for your answer:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment - I was just addressing the overflow issue. Anyway I'm glad you found the answer with substituting top:100px with margin-top:100px. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/AhSzg/2/

Remove `position:relative` from `#profileInfo`

Only use `postion` if you need it to act a different way that the default. Or remove the `top:100px`